# Caliburn.Micro(UWP) : How to make Wizard?

Tags: uwp, caliburn.micro

With Caliburn.Micro (UWP), I am making a wizard page to setup something.

**What's Wizard ?**
Wizard mean , First show page 1, input sometime. If all is OK, 
Next, We display page2, page3..... and start application.

[image]

Like this image, ShellViewModel is a based ViewModel. From this class, We call :

```
ActivateItem(Page_1_ViewModel);
ActivateItem(Page_2_ViewModel);
ActivateItem(Page_3_ViewModel);
```

Each page has logic to determine whether we can go next page or stay. We do not put this logic on ShellViewModel.

**Question** 
Is there any good way to switch page ? I want to call something to switch on ShellViewModel from each page. Difficult point is each page is on shell. We can not call anything on Shell from each page. ( Can you understand ? )

**Here is my way.** 
If you have more better way, Please share idea.

My plan is to use EventAggregator. from each page, We publish a Event to order "Shell" to switch page.

Here is event message class

```
public class BaseScreenSwitchMessage
{
    public BaseScreenSwitchMessage(Type _nextScreenType)
    {
        NextScreenType = _nextScreenType;
    }

    public Type NextScreenType { get; }
}
```

and Each page can order "Shell" to switch page.

```
await _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(new BaseScreenSwitchMessage(typeof(Page_2_ViewModel)));
```

ShellViewModel has this method to switch page.

```
public void Handle(BaseScreenSwitchMessage message)
    {
        ActivateItem(Activator.CreateInstance(message.NextScreenType));
    }
```

**Is there any good way ?**

At least, Above way worked fine. I can switch page1->2->3...

Comment: Is there any issue in above way to switch page? If not, it seems you can use it.

Comment: from Page_1 to ShellViewModel, without EventAggregator, Is there any way to tell a order ? Bubbling ?